# Alternative to $eval Executing Function in Angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, rootscope

I have a custom element directive (shows a user's picture and name) that can take a number of different configuration attributes. The `uc-on-hover` attribute can take a function to determine what element to display when the user hovers over the DOM element. Currently, the logic for the function is located on the $rootScope (defined in an angular service). The directive logic performs an `$eval(attr['ucOnHover'])` to execute the function on the $rootScope. While this pattern works well for the time being, I am afraid that its too complex and the $rootScope can become unwieldy. Is there anyway I can change the solution design while still paying attention to separation of concerns of both the directive and service and making a flexible solution?

My custom element directive in the context of a view:

```
<user-card locator="{{ Item.Author }}" uc-on-hover="$root.namespace.displayFloatingContainer()"></user-card>
```

The service defining $rootScope.namespace.displayFloatingContainer():

```
.service('uiElementService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.ngRestForm.displayFloatingContainer = function (code) {

            try {
                console.log('rootscope.uielementservice hit with code: ' + code);
                return true;
            } catch (err) {
            }
        return false;
        };       
}])
 .run(function (uiElementService) {
     console.log('uiElementService: Start');
 });
```

The directive calls the function on the $rootScope by:

```
$scope.$eval(attrs["ucOnHover"]);
```

Any help on this design would be appreciated.

Comment: $scope.$apply(attrs['ucOnHover']); ?

Comment: Does the `user-card` directive use an isolate scope?

Comment: yes, the `user-card` directive uses an isolate scope.

Comment: I tried @Baszz suggestion and received the error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress this does not occur when simply $scope.$eval(attrs['ucOnHover']) is used

Answer (score 0):

You could use $parse, and run the function within the directives scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

Your service could be injected into wherever the function you're executing is defined, and invoked from the function that you're running.

Here's a barebones skeleton of a uc-on-hover directive that fires a function passed in as part of an array of arguments

```
(function() {

angular
  .module('yourModuleName')
  .directive('ucOnHover', ucOnHover);

ucOnHover.$inject = ['$parse'];

function ucOnHover($parse) {

var directive = {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: link
}

return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  var args = attrs['ucOnHover'].split(' ');

  var hoverFunctions = [];

  angular.forEach(args, function(hoverFunc) {
      hoverFunctions.push($parse(hoverFunc));
  });

  element.on('hover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    scope.$apply(function() {
      angular.forEach(hoverFunctions, function(hoverFn) {
         hoverFn(scope);
       });
    });
  });


}


}

})();
```

Here's the same directive used in the template

```
<user-card locator="{{ Item.Author }}" uc-on-hover="hoverFunction()"                                         ></user-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Right now I have the function defined within the service. I am using the service as a way of organizing related functions that are defined on the $rootScope. (example signature: $rootScope.ngRestForm.displayFloatingContainer). An alternative to this style of organization would be to extract functions like displayFloatingContainer() outside the service to a global object that can be accessed from the view. There has to be a better way of organizing what I want to do while leaving the directive decoupled from the logic within displayFloatingContainer().

Comment: As a side note it is good to know that I can inject providers into any function.Although its frequency of use is another discussion.